# How to check another row if value exists?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is driving me nuts. I have dumped the imdb db using imdbpy. I'm trying to find US movies that have the actor data available by the first letter of the movie.

Below is an example of a query that fetches the movies without acto data. This runs pretty quick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title.id,title.title,title.production_year
FROM  title

INNER JOIN movie_info ON
(movie_info.movie_id =  title.id
AND
movie_info.info_type_id = 8
AND
movie_info.info =  'USA') 

WHERE  title LIKE  'a%'
AND  title.kind_id =  1
LIMIT 75
```

The cast data is stored in a separate table called `cast_info` and contains about 22 million records. The `nr_order` column contains the order of credits for actors in a movie. For example, Tom Hank would be 1 in Forrest Gump. There are typically dozens of rows for each `movie_id`.

So to check to see if the actor data is available, there should be at least one row that isn't null for that particular `movie_id`. If all the values in `nr_order` for a `movie_id` are null, it does NOT contain the data I need.

To attempt to grab this information is used the query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title.id,title.title,title.production_year
FROM  title

INNER JOIN movie_info ON
(movie_info.movie_id =  title.id
AND
movie_info.info_type_id = 8
AND
movie_info.info =  'USA') 

INNER JOIN cast_info ON 
(cast_info.movie_id = title.id
AND
cast_info.nr_order = 1)

WHERE  title LIKE  'a%'
AND  title.kind_id =  1
LIMIT 75
```

For some reason the query becomes very slow. It takes .3-.7 for the first query and about 6-10 seconds for the second. I added an index on `cast_info`.`nr_order` but it didn't help.

The EXPLAIN output:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys                                    | key               | key_len | ref          | rows  | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | title     | range | PRIMARY,title_idx_title,fk_kind_type_id_4        |  title_idx_title  | 257     | NULL         | 132801| Using where; Using temporary|
|  1 | SIMPLE      | movie_info| ref   | ovie_info_idx_mid,info_type_id movie_info_idx_mid| movie_info_idx_mid| 4       | imdb.title.id| 4     | Using where; Distinct       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1    | ref   | cast_info_idx_mid,nr_order                       | cast_info_idx_mid | 4       | imdb.title.id| 12    | Using where; Distinct       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------+
```

Any ideas would be very helpful!

EDIT: EXPLAIN from 1st query

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys                                    | key               | key_len | ref          | rows  | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | title     | range | PRIMARY,title_idx_title,fk_kind_type_id_4        |  title_idx_title  | 257     | NULL         | 132801| Using where; Using temporary|
|  1 | SIMPLE      | movie_info| ref   | ovie_info_idx_mid,info_type_id movie_info_idx_mid| movie_info_idx_mid| 4       | imdb.title.id| 4     | Using where; Distinct       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Try removing the join conditions, and putting them in the WHERE clause instead.  Filtering should only be done in the WHERE clause to ensure proper index usage.

Comment: What's the `EXPLAIN` for your first query?

Comment: added EXPLAIN for 1st query. Also I did try what you suggested @sybkar previously but the speed was the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only concerned with whether there *is* or *is not* cast information available, you could try using `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title.id,title.title,title.production_year
FROM  title

INNER JOIN movie_info ON
(movie_info.movie_id =  title.id
AND
movie_info.info_type_id = 8
AND
movie_info.info =  'USA') 

WHERE  title LIKE  'a%'
AND  title.kind_id =  1
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cast_info WHERE cast_info.movie_id = title.id AND cast_info.nr_order IS NOT NULL)
LIMIT 75
```

I'm not sure exactly the explanation for your behavior, but the `DISTINCT` could be doing something funny with lots of rows on the join - or at least lots of rows on the joined product - (note the Distinct being applied to the cast_info table in the explain).

Comment: The INNER JOIN for `cast_info` can be removed. I guess the DISTINCT can too. That helped get it down to about 4 seconds but I'm shooting for under 1.

Comment: @john Sorry, I meant to remove it.

Comment: Is there only one `movie_info` row for each `title` then?

Comment: Each `title` has a `movie_id`. Each `movie_id` inside the `movie_info` table has dozens of rows. The `cast_info`.`nr_order` column is NULL by default. If there is any value at inside `cast_info`.`nr_order` for the `movie_id`, it would match.